# How to bind dropdownlist in radgrid

Tags: telerik-grid

I am new to use telerik  controls. I want to bind data in dropdownlist that is in telerik RadGrid control. I have already been applied but it gives an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my code given below :

Source code

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="false"              AllowPaging="true"
    OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand"
    OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated" OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand"
    OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" 
    onitemdatabound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" >
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id" CommandItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true"
                ForceExtractValue="Always" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldept"  DataTextField="name" DataValueField="id"   runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="code" HeaderText="Branch Code" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="name" HeaderText="Branch Name" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="shortname" HeaderText="Branch Shorth Name" />
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="hod" HeaderText="Head of Department"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="location" HeaderText="Location Address" />
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmText="Are you sure want to delete this Branch?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                ConfirmTitle="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" />
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
    <ClientSettings>
        <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="rowDblClick" />
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Main Code

```
  protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
   {
            DataTable dt=obj.display_branch();
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            DropDownList list = item.FindControl("ddldept") as DropDownList;
            list.DataSource = dt;
            list.DataTextField = "name";
            list.DataValueField = "id";
            list.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try on RadGrid1_ItemCreated. That is how I achieved it.